# Which knot is best for connecting loose ends and attaching carabiner?

Tags: ropes, knots

I have a short climbing rope and two carabiners. I want to use it as a strap to carry something (it is **not** intended for climbing). As the rope is too long, I fold it once. At one "end" I make a figure eight loop and attach a carabiner to it.

Which knot do I use to

- connect the two loose ends on the other side *and*
- make it possible to attach a carabiner there that is not sliding on the rope?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

There is no right answer, and we cannot know enough detail to give you the best answer.

I would tie the middle of the rope to the carabiner with a clove hitch, rather than a fig8 as you have described.

At the other end, the easy and most reliable option is Two fig 8's tied at the correct length (one could be on a bite). If you want to make the length easy to adjust, you could use Clove Hitch at one or both ends. If using a clove hitch, be aware that if the rope is cycled from slack to tight, they can loosen and move. In this case, especially if its life critical and the knot is unattended, you can tie of the dead end of the rope  with a half hitch.

Answer (score 0):

The figure 8 is fine on the half-way end (I’d probably use a figure 9… less likely to jam under load and it won’t shift like a clove is prone to do between loadings). On the remaining loose ends, I’d use the always-reliable Double Fisherman’s Bend. Pull most of the tails toward the knots as you dress it, so the bend stays concise. You’re not climbing, so pull-through isn’t a critical concern here. You now have a contiguous rope.  At that end, make an Alpine Butterfly Loop, capturing the Fisherman within it. Before you snug it, pull most of the slack out of the loop as you dress it. Your rope ends are  now doubly secured against separation and you have a nice little knurl within the AB to keep your carabiner oriented and in place.